# Facebook like button late rendering

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-like, addthis

I am using addthis thirdparty tool for facebook and twitter like button , The twitter like button rendering parallely with the page but facebbok button renders a bit late, after the whole page, I am using it like that :

a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:href="#"

Is there a way for rendering it same time with the whole page ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to guarantee when the buttons will be rendered.  All the buttons will load at different times depending on how fast the resources (JS/CSS) are loaded and how quickly the code executes to render the buttons.  This is done to make sure your page always load and doesn't get blocked by the buttons loading.  The reverse could happen where Twitter loads slowly and Facebook loads quickly.  Is there a functional reason for wanting them to load at the same time?  If so, you could "hide" the div containing all the buttons and then have them all appears after a certain amount of time to increase the likelihood that all buttons have been rendered.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Actually I dont have a functional reason for that.It was just for good appearance